# Specifying the minimum python version required for a module in pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Is there a way to specify the minimum python version required for installing a module in pip?

I am trying to publish a package to pypi.

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
```

Is the command I am using. However in setup.py there is no way to specify that the minimum python version (in my case python 3.5) is needed to run this module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the version of the python required for your project by using:

```
python_requires='>=3.5'
```

The above code must be specified in `setup.py` ,also only versions 9.0.0 and higher of pip recognize the `python_requires` metadata.

Additionally in `setup.py` to specify the dependences:

```
setup(
install_requires=['dependent functions,classes,etc'],
)
```

Comment: also `setuptools>=24.2.0` must be installed for python_requires to work properly.

Answer (score 4):

First thing is to document what minimal Python version is required for your package. Include that info in README and in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
      …
      long_description=open('README.rst', 'rU').read(),
      classifiers=[
          …
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
          …
      ],
      …
)
```

Second, forbid bad versions at runtime somewhere near the top of `setup.py`:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 5):
    raise RuntimeError("This package requres Python 3.5+")
```